# Limit user1 access to allow wired connection only, allow user2 access to wired and wireless access

Tags: networking, users

I have a VPN client router installed behind my normal router. My laptop is hard wired to the VPN router and is connected wireless to the normal router. I would like to limit user1 access to the web to only be through the VPN (wired connection). But, I want user2 to be allowed access via wired or wireless. Is there an easy way to do this? TIA

Comment: Login to user2 then go to Wi-Fi settings then edit your wireless connection and uncheck *make available to other users*.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I've found would be to (on a `sudo` capable account) create a Systemd service file in `/etc/systemd/system/` with something like the following (replacing `<user>` and `<wireless interface>` with their respective values):

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable wireless for user <user>
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o <wireless interface> -m owner --uid-owner <user> -j DROP
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/iptables -D OUTPUT -o <wireless interface> -m owner --uid-owner <user> -j DROP
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Name it something like `disable-wireless-<user>.service`, then run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` followed by `sudo systemctl enable --now disable-wireless-<user>`.

You can find a list of network interfaces on your system via the `ip link` command, which will display something like this:

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ??:??:??:??:??:?? brd ??:??:??:??:??:??
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ??:??:??:??:??:?? brd ??:??:??:??:??:??
```

In this case, `wlp3s0` would be the wireless interface.